# MacHighway PHP Session Variables

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I am building a site in PHP. The site utilizes PHP session variables. Users can select courses to add to a schedule (each course is stored as an array, and all courses are stored within an array), and then they are directed to a display page, which gets each course and prints it out. I developed the site in the Cloud9 web IDE, and everything works fine. I am ready to host the site, so I purchased a domain and server space with MacHighway. I moved the code over and the session variables aren't working. My display page shows that there are no courses inside the array, and indeed, when I print the array out, it is empty. I have tried messing around with the session.save_path variable (defaults to "/tmp"), thinking maybe they weren't being saved in the correct place, but it is not helping. The PHP version is the same on both servers (both PHP 5.5).

Any other ideas as to what might be causing this error? I tend to believe it has to do with the PHP settings, because it works fine on my development server, but not after I move it.

P.S. error reporting is turned on, and there are no errors being reported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the session id being passed between scripts, resp. _is_ it getting passed? Check the other session settings as well, such as `session.use_cookies`, `session.use_only_cookies`, `session.use_trans_sid` and `session.auto_start` (in case you have been relying on the latter, instead of explicitly starting the session yourself.)

Comment: Can you show us a reproductible part of your code ?

Comment: I start the session at the top of each script. session.auto_start is turned off, but it is off on both servers. All of the other settings are the same on both servers as well. I would show some of the code, but it is a rather large project, with a few thousand lines of code and multiple pages.